# how can I execute an sql query string with Datetime.now correctly in c#?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

```
Connection.Open();
string dd = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); 
string qry = "UPDATE TAccount SET Amount = Amount +" +
              a.transactionAmount.ToString() +
              " WHERE ID = " + a.ID.ToString() +
          " insert into TransactionHistory (ID, CardNumber, Amount, TransactionDate)
        values ((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TransactionHistory)+1, " +
           a.ID.ToString() + " , " + a.transactionAmount.ToString() +
           " , " + dd.ToString() + ")";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, Connection);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close();
```

I get the following error when executing the following query while in VB.Net i don't get any issue executing the same query.

"
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
"

I removed the date and it worked fine but when i added the date back still the same thing

I appreciate any help

Comment: You just call GETDATE() in sql -- no need to call local, convert to string and send to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right thing here should be using sql parameters, and not sending the current time at all for this purpose.Any way, this seems like a casting issue - instead of `dd.ToString()` wrap it with `'` and use the server datetime format (BTW the format '2010-01-28' should always works..).

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer "in no way". Don't use local time for logging activity, use server time i.e. `getdate()`. Don't user string concatenation in your queries it is error prone and an open door for sql injection. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Hey no problem, I had a chuckle hopefully you did too with my edit comment :D

Comment: :) The English is a fanny language. :D